# Is the following model correct for a DAPP?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, react

I am trying to make a DAPP using React Native.
I have made a flowchart of all the pieces i need to build in order for it to work.

I was hoping if someone could verify it so that I can start working on it.
[image]

Comment: This is the exact flow for building a dApp. Go ahead :)

Comment: I'd put truffle between react and web3js, because it provides additional functionality on top of web3js.